# Magento2 URL Rewrites

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite

## System: Magento 2.1.4 on 1and1 Cloud, CentOS

Searching throughout the web, I haven't found any specific help with this

I am wanting to change URLs in Magento2. There are URLs are like this:
( https://domain/page.html?background_color_name=510 ). I'd like it to read ( https://domain/page/pink-purple/ ). Selecting this URL displays products with this attribute.

What is the best practice of implementing this in Magento 2.1.4? If there is more than one way, GREAT!

Any assistance is appreciated.

FYI:
There are over 10,000 products

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a router that will catch requests for a specific route and use the additional url component as a request parameter.

For example, say you have a route call `rewrite` and you want requests for `rewrite/pink-purple` to be forwarded to `rewrite/index/index` with a request parameter named `background` that would be `pink-purple`. Here's what the router to do this might look like `Some\Module\Controller\Router.php`:

```
<?php


namespace Some\Module\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface;

class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;

    public function __construct(ActionFactory $actionFactory)
    {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return ActionInterface
     */
    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $path = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $parts = explode('/', $path);

        if ($parts && $parts[0] === 'rewrite') {

            if (isset($parts[1])) {
                $request->setParams(['background' => $parts[1]]);
            }

            $request->setModuleName('rewrite')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('index');
            /** @var ActionInterface */
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you have to add the router to the router list. In `etc/frontend/di.xml` you have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="paramsRedirect" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Some\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```